# stop Visual Studio profiler from randomly flattening the profile result

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, profiler

This might be a Visual Studio's bug. (?)

With the **same** build (i.e. no recompilation), for each profiling-run, Visual Studio 2015 randomly creates **Detailed report** in 2 different types :-

- A flatten one : It tends to show the most expensive functions.
- A tree one : It correctly show collective CPU cost in a tree-like manner.

### Example

Here are the two results from a profiling.

[image]

- In the upper image, the report shows the most expensive functions `#1` and `#2`.
  `#1` and `#2`  are actually called very deep inside the main function (inside `#3`).
  Visual Studio ignores the fact.
- In the lower image, it correctly shows that .exe call `__scrt_common_main_sech`, and the `__scrt_common_main_sech` call `main` and so on.

### Question

Does anyone know a way to force Visual Studio to generate the report only in the tree style?

Strangely, I noticed that this issue doesn't exist when my solution is relatively small.

Comment: You must have the PDB files for any DLLs you use to get it reliably broken down by individual function.  If you don't have them then it doesn't matter that much since it is unlikely that you can improve such a DLL.

Comment: @Hans Passant  (refer to the lower image) All code start from `Test.exe` to `Looper#3` is inside my current solution.  Visual Studio should be able to break down it, at least that `#3` level. (no?)  Hmm, I will check the `.pdb`, thank.

Comment: I see "ogremain.dll" and "nvoglv32.dll", those are not DLLs that you wrote.  You did not write __scrt_common_main_sech either, also present in a DLL that isn't yours.  Getting PDBs from the Microsoft symbol server is critical for that one.  PDBs are critical to get details, it doesn't get any simpler than that.  Focus only the code that you can actually improve, your code, no point in fretting over code you didn't and can't change.